# what is replacement of com.sun.javafx.runtime API in javafx 2.1?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I am doing convert code from javafx 1.3 to javafx 2.1. But I face this problem. So please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing in the JavaFX 1.3 javafx.runtime package was a test of platform conditional features.

For JavaFX 2.1, the [javafx.application.Platform.isSupported(ConditionalFeature)](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#isSupported%28javafx.application.ConditionalFeature%29) method is equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        javafxuicomponent.setText("text to display");
    }
});
```

instead of

```
Entry.deferAction(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        fxListener.onMessage(line);
    }
});
```